# jquery: how to work with elements in area of specified html element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I set `img.src` only for specified the `img`? `select` and target `img` must have the same parent div.

```js
$(".selector").change(function() {
  $(".target_image").attr("src", $(".selector").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="selector">
    <option value='src1'>1</option>
    <option value='src2'>2</option>
  </select>
  <img class='target_image' src='' \>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="selector">
    <option value='src3'>1</option>
    <option value='src4'>2</option>
  </select>
  <img class='target_image' src='' \>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use DOM traversal to find the target element starting from the element which invoked the event.  For example:

```
$(".selector").change(function(){
    $(this).closest("div").find(".target_image").attr("src", $(this).val());
});
```

This starts at `this`, which is the instance of `.selector` that raised the change event, navigates to the closest parent `div`, then searches that `div` for matching `.target_image` elements (of which there is one).  Then it sets the `src` attribute on that element to the value of the `.selector` which raised the event.

Note that any jQuery DOM navigation, whether traversing up and then back down or whether traversing across sibling elements, is subject to breaking if the DOM structure ever changes.  It's up to you to decide which changes are more likely or less likely than others.

Answer (score 2):

Use `siblings` function to select the image that is a sibling of the currently selected element, use `$(this).val()` to get the value of the current selected element

```
$(".selector").change(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".target_image").attr("src",$(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".selector").change(function(){
    $(this).parents().find('img.target_image').attr('src',$(this).val());
});
```

- `$(".selector").change(function()`trigger when change the select box
- `$(this).parents()`  get the parent element of the select box
- `.find('img.target_image')` find the img tag with class
  `target_image`
- `.attr('src',$(this).val());` set current change
  selected value to image src

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the following code will work. Because in your case `image` is the next element of the `.selector` so it can be traverse by `next()` method. You can read more about jQuery's `next()` method [here](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$(".selector").change(function(){
    $(this).next("#target_image").attr("src",$(this).val())
});
```

or:

```
$(".selector").change(function(){
    $(this).parent().find("#target_image").attr("src",$(this).val())
});
```

jQuery `parent()` method selects the parent of the element and only travels a single level up the DOM tree, and then we can find the `image` inside it.